# Accessing properties across views

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

What is the efficient way to access and change properties from controllers in views?  I have multiple views within views.  I have to change the property of `parentView` without referring `this.get('parentView.property')`, since I reuse views often and the hierarchy changes a lot.

How to maintain variables across views effectively in ember.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the properties of views, are not binded as models, One way I follow is use common controller between the views and observe controller's property.

Eg.

```
 App.TestController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        commonProperty: "Val1"
    });

    App.View1 = Ember.View.extend({
        ObserverCommonProperty : function() {
             //runs code 
        }.observes('controller.commonProperty')
    });
    App.View2 = Ember.View.extend({
        didInsertElement: function() {
            this.get('controller').set('commonProperty',"Val2");
        }
    });
```

This way you will not be worried about the existence of other view objects and doesn't break any MVC rules

Comment: can we maintain these things within content array itself.

Comment: no..content as u said is an array..the properties may be different types and also if you keep an observer on an array, it may run every time when there is change on unrelated value...